# Cordova database in Windows 8.1

Tags: cordova, storage

I'am trying to develop a hybrid mobile app using Cordova.In android SQLite database is working fine.But  SQLite ,WebSQL,indexeddb are not working in windows 8.1.It shows an error regarding 'openDatabase()'.Local storage is working properly.But how can we store persistent data in local storage?Can you suggest me an alternate solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To use SQLite on Windows 8.1 you will need to use this plugin from microsoft:

https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-websql